# No native splash screen registered for given view controller. Call 'SplashScreen.show' for given view controller first in expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, splash-screen

Splash Screen was working fine, but suddenly it started to warn like this. I don't know what is affecting it. Help me with it.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import axios from 'axios';

// Navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { AuthContext } from './src/AuthContext';
import * as Icons from 'react-native-heroicons/outline'
import * as IconsSolid from 'react-native-heroicons/solid'
import { BASE_API_URL } from './src/Config';

// Screens
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import FeedScreen from './screens/FeedScreen';
import PeopleScreen from './screens/PeopleScreen';
import AddPostScreen from './screens/AddPostScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';

const Stack = Platform.OS == 'android' ? createStackNavigator() : createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const tab_icon_color = '#000'
const tab_icon_size = 30

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()

function LoggedInTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          height: 50,
        }
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
            return (
              focused ? <IconsSolid.HomeIcon color={tab_icon_color} size={tab_icon_size} /> : <Icons.HomeIcon color={tab_icon_color} size={tab_icon_size} />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="People" component={PeopleScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
            return (
              focused ? <IconsSolid.UsersIcon color={tab_icon_color} size={tab_icon_size} /> : <Icons.UsersIcon color={tab_icon_color} size={tab_icon_size} />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
            return (
              focused ? <IconsSolid.UserIcon color={tab_icon_color} size={tab_icon_size} /> : <Icons.UserIcon color={tab_icon_color} size={tab_icon_size} />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
            return (
              focused ? <IconsSolid.Cog6ToothIcon color={tab_icon_color} size={tab_icon_size} /> : <Icons.Cog6ToothIcon color={tab_icon_color} size={tab_icon_size} />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function LoggedInStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        gestureEnabled: true,
        gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
        ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
      }}
      headerMore="float"
    >
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

// Main Export
export default function App({ navigation }) {

  const [userGlobalToken, setUserGlobalToken] = useState(null)
  const [userGlobalData, setUserGlobalData] = useState(null)
  const [isAppLoading, setIsAppLoading] = useState(true)
  const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            userToken: action.token,
            userData: action.data,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: false,
            userToken: action.token,
            userData: action.data,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: true,
            userToken: null,
            userData: null,
          };
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignout: false,
      userToken: null,
      userData: null,
    }
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      setIsAppLoading(true)

      let userToken;
      let userData;

      try {
        userToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('userToken');
        userData = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('userData')
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }

      // CODE TO GET UPDATED DATA OF THE USER HERE AND VERIFY THE TOKEN
      setUserGlobalToken(JSON.parse(userToken))
      setUserGlobalData(JSON.parse(userData))
      setIsAppLoading(false)
      dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken, data: userData });
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const checkLoginState = async () => {
      if (loginState.isLoading == false) {
        try {
          await SplashScreen.hideAsync()
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('SplashHide '+e)
        }
      }
    }
    checkLoginState();
  }, [loginState.isLoading])

  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async (userProfileToken, userProfileData) => {
        // Signing in the user and storing user token and user data in Secure Store
        try {
          await SecureStore.setItemAsync('userToken', JSON.stringify(userProfileToken))
          await SecureStore.setItemAsync('userData', JSON.stringify(userProfileData))
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
        }

        setUserGlobalToken(userProfileToken)
        setUserGlobalData(userProfileData)

        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: userProfileToken, data: userProfileData });
      },
      // Sigining out user by making the Secure Store values null (token and data)
      signOut: async () => {
        try {
          await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('userToken')
          await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('userData')
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' })
      },
    }), []);

  // Returning the Stack (Conditional)
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ ...authContext, userGlobalToken, userGlobalData, setUserGlobalData }}
    >
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            gestureEnabled: true,
            gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
            ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
          }}
          headerMore="float"
          
        >
          {
            loginState.userToken == null ? (
              // Logged Out Stack
              <>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}
                  options={{ animationTypeForReplace: loginState.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push', headerStyle: {height: 45} }}
                />
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                {/* Logged In Stack */}
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={LoggedInTabs} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Add Post" component={AddPostScreen} options={{ presentation: 'modal' }} />
              </>
            )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Also help me to show SpalshScreen while the Token is fetched from SecureStore. I tried but it still it shows Login screen and goes to Home stack.
I use Expo, and I use the SplashScreen from Expo.

Thanks in advance!